# Change background image according to user ID and avoid CSP unsafe-inline

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to avoid using unsafe-inline on style-src in my CSP header, but I have a problem with a background image.
I change the background image of a specific element according to the ID of the user, therefore I can not have the background image url in the style.css, as I normally would do, because it will be different for each user.

I thought about changing it through Javascript, but then I will still have unsafe inline style if i do something like this

```
document.getElementById("picture").style.backgroundImage = "url('img'+ID)";
```

So is there any way to change the background image dynamically according to ID of the user AND avoid having style-src unsafe inline?

The code I have right now looks like this:

```
echo '<div id="imagePreview'.$row['ID'].'"  style="background-image: url(\'billeder/'.$row['ID'].'.jpg);"></div>';
```

Comment: php or js will be unsafe if you are referencing your image with the user ID. To avoid changes based on the ID I would suggest you to have something like a random hash for each user, so no one can try other images without knowing the proper hash.

Comment: What is the policy of CSP header now?

Comment: @MarcelKohls Okay I will try using hash, is it the hash-value, that is suggested from the console you are thinking of? like in the example under 'Using hashes' in this link https://www.troyhunt.com/locking-down-your-website-scripts-with-csp-hashes-nonces-and-report-uri/

Comment: @MoorthyG I had just set it to report-only and style-src 'self', as I'm in developing state. So I haven't got a full policy yet

Comment: @DVP, take a look on this link for a simple example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php - With this approach you keep your user ID hidded.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic stylesheet might help you. If you can't control CSP header.

You should process one css file via php.

You can find more information at => http://thisinterestsme.com/dynamic-css-stylesheet-php/

```php
<?php

// Set the content-type header and charset.
header("Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8");

// Somehow get background image
$backgroundImage = "url(yourimage.jpg);"; 
?>

/** CSS begins **/
#imagePreview{
    background-image: <?= $backgroundImage ; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that :)